# Why does my portfolio website take a long time to load?

Tags: javascript, css, web

When first visiting my site it stays on the splash screen for about a minute. I was wondering if it had to do with the file size of my pictures of my HTML and CSS code? You can check the HTML code by viewing the page source. I will add the CSS code if needed.

Here is my website: [Tom Falzani Portfolio Website.](http://tomfalzani.com/)

Comment: philly.png 200 png (index) 6.6 MB 17.17 s - simple use of dev-tools reveals the loading time (without any caching). You have several large images on there, but `philly.png` is probably the reason for the delay.

Comment: `philly.png` and `philly_scene` seem to be huge files which are loaded. Do compress them. Also use [Google pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftomfalzani.com%2F) which suggests potential fixes on your website.

Comment: you can see [here](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/d4Xuaz/http://tomfalzani.com/)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you meets performance issue, don't forget the network tab of your browser's developper debbuging tool. See [Google Network Performance Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/).

Here is a record of the initialisation and loading of your website, and if we take a deeper look at it, we see that the *philly_scene.png* file makes 6.3 MB and take 25 seconds to load and that the *philly.png* file makes 6.6 MB and takes 18 seconds.

[image: record]

To avoid this long loading time, you can try to ajust the both size of them using [this link, for exemple](https://compressor.io/). (Never used)
Or you can them [asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/async_function) and deliver a first render of your website until they are actually loaded.
If you're using jQuery, take a look at the [.load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/), there is also many others ways to do it like the [Axios Promise](https://github.com/axios/axios) or the [Async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) if you're using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)